# Histogram with arbitrary bin edges with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I draw a histogram with arbitrary bin edges using Highcharts?
I can't figure it out from their [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.histogram) or [examples](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram). Or do they only support uniform binning?

For concreteness, lets say I want the following bin edges,

```
[ 0, 1, 5, 10, 20 ]
```

with the bin values

```
[ 100, 50, 30, 7 ]
```

respectively.

Comment: Histogram is a very specialized chart if I remember correct (been a few months since I was using highcharts), more or less it's a bar chart with specific options. It'll probably be easier to just customize a standard bar chart with your own labels/options and use pointWidth parameter to set custom widths on the 'bins'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Histogram series data is computed based on values from other series (`baseSeries` option) - it's rather hard to manipulate it. Maybe **varwide** series is what you're looking for: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variwide